# invalid syntax python

Tags: python

```
     print(f"str{kaf.a:a}{kaf.b:c}")
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

что в этом коде не так почему синтаксическую ошибку выдает?

Comment: вы хотите так? `print(f"str{kaf.a}:{a}{kaf.b}:{c}")`

Comment: Из вопроса сложно понять, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Пожалуйста, объясните подробнее.

Comment: А как это должно отработать - `kaf.a:a` по ваши ожиданиям?

Comment: Вы используете pytohn2 (а код предназначен для python3).

Comment: @Chorkov, именно) спс еще три символа

Comment: @Alpensin а что это вообще такое?

Comment: @user561212 Это ваш код.

Comment: @Chorkov, код не мой, как на второй питон переписать такой вывод?

Answer (score 4):

Как уже вам написали в комментариях, ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы запускаете код какой-то старой версией Python (более старой, чем Python 3.6), где еще нет синтаксиса f-строк.

По поводу адаптации под старые версии Python:

В целом, такая строка `f"{x:y}"` аналогична `"{:y}".format(x)` или `format(x, "y")` (и это во всех случаях превращается в вызов `x.__format__("y")`).

Например,

```
x = 1
print(f"{x:010}")
print("{:010}".format(x))
print(format(x, "010"))
print(x.__format__("010"))
```

во всех случаях выведет `0000000001` (010 в данном случае означает "добить нулями слева до 10 символов").

Поэтому чисто механически ваш код перевести в стиль `format` можно, например, так:

```
print("str{:a}{:c}".format(kaf.a, kaf.b))
```

и это может работать старых версиях Python, в том числе и на Python 2, при условии что у объектов, записанных в полях `kaf.a` и `kaf.b` реализован метод `__format__`, который будет понимать, что за такое `a` и `с`.

Пример такого кода (адаптировано под Python 2):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function


class Field(object):
    def __format__(self, spec):
        # Для примера берем спецификатор форматирования (то что после двоеточия)
        # и переводим в верхний регистр
        return spec.upper()  


class Kaf(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = Field()
        self.b = Field()


kaf = Kaf()

print("str{:a}{:c}".format(kaf.a, kaf.b))
```

Вывод:

```
strAC
```

Смысла именно в таком коде не много, но в принципе для своего класса с помощью переопределения метода `__format__` можно реализовать какие-то свои обозначения, что-то похожее на [спецификаторы форматирования чисел](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), например.

Comment: что в первом вопросе означает символ "с"

Comment: @user561212 чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, нужно видеть остальной код, а не только одну строку. Без этого контекста - ничего не означает.